# Python 3.7: Elasticsearch module not found

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm new to Python and trying to try manipulate data using 'elasticsearch'. Initially I am just trying to connect using their standard [example](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

I succesfully installed the package using 
`pip install elasticsearch`

When running the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
}
res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
print(res['result'])

res = es.get(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1)
print(res['_source'])

es.indices.refresh(index="test-index")

res = es.search(index="test-index", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
print("Got %d Hits:" % res['hits']['total']['value'])
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    print("%(timestamp)s %(author)s: %(text)s" % hit["_source"])
```

I get the following error:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\USERNAME\Dropbox\Stuff\Python\Elasticsearch.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USERNAME\Dropbox\Stuff\Python\Elasticsearch.py", line 10, in <module>
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elasticsearch
```

I looked around and heard something about a *.bash_profile* but I do not understand what that means?
My environment variable for PYTHONPATH contains
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7`

Comment: Renaming didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python path probably only contains an alias to the Python executable, but it's trying to import stuff from there. You should open `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7` 
and get the *Target* from right click > properties on the Python executable.

Set the PYTHONPATH to whatever that path is. It will probably look like `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`.

Comment: I am facing the same on Ubuntu, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: for Ubuntu run with sudo fixd the problem to me:  sudo python3 -m pip install elasticsearch